# Significance of Torah Midpoint

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, aleph-bet-letters, parashat-shemini

What is the significance of the middle of the Torah in letters being the vav in גָּחוֹן ([Vayika 11:42](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.42?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=bi&p3=Kiddushin.30a&lang3=bi))? (source: [Kiddushin 30a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.30a.11-13?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

What is special about the vav in גָּחוֹן that the Almighty chose to make it the middle of the Torah in letters?

> כֹּל הוֹלֵךְ עַל־גָּחוֹן וְכֹל הוֹלֵךְ עַל־אַרְבַּע עַד כָּל־מַרְבֵּה
>   רַגְלַיִם לְכָל־הַשֶּׁרֶץ הַשֹּׁרֵץ עַל־הָאָרֶץ לֹא תֹאכְלוּם
>   כִּי־שֶׁקֶץ הֵם׃
>
> You shall not eat, among all things that swarm upon the earth,
>   anything that crawls on its belly, or anything that walks on fours, or
>   anything that has many legs; for they are an abomination.

Comment: The Gra has a nice explanation on this ,have to find it